# Camel pollEnrich and xml 'prettyPrint'

Tags: apache-camel

I am attempting to use Camel's pollEnrich feature, but it is not behaving *as I would like*...  I'm not saying it's broken, but wondering if there is a way to get the behavior I desire.  That is, I have an XML (blueprint) defined route that goes something like this:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:a" />
    <pollEnrich uri="http:www.somewebsite.com?format=application/xml" />
    <to uri="log:com.acme?level=WARN&amp;showStreams=true" />
</route>
```

Now, the response normally comes back just fine (e.g., in a web browser).  The *problem* seems to be that it is not just on one line, and for some reason Camel reads each line, sequentially into the same buffer, starting at character zero...  so what we end up with is one messy line in the output from the pollEnrich.  That is, the `to uri="log...` line prints messages like:

```
2015-05-26 13:55:26,379 | WARN  | a.distr.topic.B] | contentEnrich |
?     ? | 142 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.12.0.redhat-610379 |
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: 
org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache, Body: 

<?xml versi</ElementStatus> ]pe></Status>nd>gin>ys for this element.</Reason>>ame>
```

*(last line vertically offset for emphasis)*

I cannot seem to find a way to tell Camel that the result will be in 'prettPrint' format...  Anyone know how?  The documentation seems to suggest that this option does not exist--in which case, I'd consider this to be a bug... though I suppose a person could argue that a custom aggregation strategy should be used (and I'd disagree with that person, citing the simplicity of this case) :)

UPDATE#1: even using org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.UseLatestAggregationStrategy produces the same effect.  (i.e., usage as below)

```
<bean id="latestStrat" 
      class="org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.UseLatestAggregationStrategy" />

<route>
    <from uri="direct:a" />
    <pollEnrich uri="http:www.somewebsite.com?format=application/xml" strategyRef="latestStrat" />
    <to uri="log:com.acme?level=WARN&amp;showStreams=true" />
</route>
```

...going to cross fingers and try org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy, but am guessing there is a configuration limitation with Camel always treating EOL characters as message delimiters.

UPDATE #2 - additional information:
The REST(GET) response received (tested with wget) has blank lines and null fields--but no carriage returns (^M).  I've tried both the http and http4 components--same result.  There is a leading `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, but no namespace/style info.  I also just noticed that tab characters have been used for the *pretty-ish* indents.  In sum, the response looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ElementStatus> 
                <Flag>false</Flag>

                <CODE>XYZ</CODE>

                <Locale>Western</Locale>
            ...
```

*(again, where the whitespace indenting has been done with tabs--AND the blank lines have a few tabs too)*

Comment: You are likely fooled by the browser which reformats XML responses and shows it pretty printed to humans. Use a low level tool which can dump the HTTP server response and it should be as Camel read's it byte by byte.

Comment: @ClausIbsen not so, unfortunately.  The response is in _pretty print-ish_ format--a couple of idiosyncrasies: 1. there are blank lines, and 2. there are <open></close> tags with no values.  Wouldn't think either of these should be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...so the "answer" is that this is an apparent limitation of (or bug within) the log component's "showStreams" logic.  I implemented Processor in a <bean>, routed the Exchange output from my pollEnrich to that <bean>, and logged the contents instead, and that matches exactly the output from wget.

FYI: this is `camel-paxlogging (2.12.0.redhat-610379)` - not sure what underlying version of camel that corresponds to, as I don't seem to have a jboss-parent-2.12.0 pom in my maven repo--which is strange, since I have other jboss-parent poms--and the red hat documentation doesn't seem to get into version composition.

FYI#2: and on a related note, when I use `GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy` it does produce a `List<Exchange>`, BUT it behaves effectively the same as `UseLatestAggregationStrategy` -- i.e., 'grouped' produces a one-item `List<Exchange>` that only has the pollEnrich result, where 'latest' produces a standalone `Exchange` object that has only the pollEnrich result.  Seems like an error in either `GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy` or `pollEnrich` ... but this will likely be the topic of my next Stack-post.